# How to return my CSV data from my service - async/await issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am attempting to load some CSV data in my API such that I can manipulate it and pass through to my front end, however I am having a few issues returning the data.

I am using [fast-csv](https://c2fo.io/fast-csv/docs/introduction/getting-started) to do the parsing here.

**service.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

module.exports.getFileContents = (filepath) => {
    let data = [];

    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .on('data', row => data.push(row))
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log(data) // This will print the full CSV file fine
            return data;
        });
};
```

**routes.js**

```
router.get('/data/:filename', (req, res) => {
  const file = FS.getFileContents(testUrl + '/' + req.params.filename + '.csv');
  console.log(file); // This prints 'undefined'
  res.send(file);
});
```

I can print out the CSV contents fine from the **service**, but I just get 'undefined' from the actual **routes**. Can somebody please point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common problem with JavaScript code, in the following.

```
.on('end', () => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
 });
```

Your on-end handler is an anonymous callback function (because of `() =>`), so when you `return data`, you are returning data out of your on-end handler callback function. You are not returning data out of your enclosing `getFileContents()` function.

Here's a typical way to write this kind of code:

```
const getFileContents = async (filepath) => {
  const data = [];

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.createReadStream(filepath)
      .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
      .on('error', error => reject(error))
      .on('data', row => data.push(row))
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      });
  });
}
```

And then, call it as follows, though this must be within an async function:

```
const data = await getFileContents('games.csv');
```

What's happened here is as follows:

- your `getFileContents` is now async and returns a promise
- the CSV data will be available when `resolve(data)` is executed
- the caller can await the fulfillment/resolution of this promise to get the data

Comment: God damn promises! I knew there was something simple missing! Thanks for the help.

Comment: JavaScript is tricky and it is quite difficult to understand this type of code first (second and third) time you run into it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in the service and return it. Once the job is done, resolve it. The returned Promise will wait until it is resolved.

**service.js**

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  const csv = require('fast-csv');

   module.exports.getFileContents = (filepath) => {
    let data = [];
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
        .on('error', error => console.error(error))
        .on('data', row => data.push(row))
        .on('end', () => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    }
  };
```

**routes.js**

```
router.get('/data/:filename', (req, res) => {
  const file = await FS.getFileContents(testUrl + '/' + req.params.filename + '.csv');
  console.log(file); // This prints only after it is resolved
  res.send(file);
});
```